# Google Analytics Event Tracking Real-time

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, analytics-events, real-time

I am trying to use Google Analytics Event Tracking to monitor clicks on certain newly added buttons on my site.

The Real-time Events report seems to show inconsistent data. The bar charts are getting the data, but the table below is showing no events. It shows "There is no data for this view."

Is the report broken, or am I just reading it wrong?

[image: screenshot of google analytics report]

Comment: Make sure you are not filtering your visits if you are testing this yourself. Also install something like the GA Debugger plugin for Chrome and see if the hits are being sent in. RT activity only shows up within a 30 minute window. Check your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your even tracking code is correct then they should show up. To troubleshoot do this:

1) Load the page that has an "event" on it using Chrome. (Page with a link that includes tracking code.)

2) Right Click and Select - **Inspect Element**

3) Switch over to the **Network** Tab and refresh your page

4) Find your GA request using the **Search Filter**. Type in the word 'collect' and it should find the request. If you don't see a GA request then it means that no analytic s are getting sent to GA.

5) If the request is there then you can trigger an events and see if the data is being captured. Click on the link that triggers an event and look for a second GA request on the **Network** Tab. Your event data will show up under '**Query String Parameters**' once you click on the request. Look for these 4 parameters -> **ec:**, **ea:**, **el:** and **ev:**

Note: If you filter your own visit by IP, you need to make sure that you are using a different View or just trigger an events from a different IP or use your mobile device but turn off your wifi on it first.